# AngularJs - $location does not return the hash

Tags: angularjs

I have a plain page where I am trying to set dynamically the anchors href attribute value as a computed value: `$location.path() + '/path_b'`.

My issue is that `$location` never returns the hash value (#) no matter what properties of it I am using (`path()`, `hash()`).

Current browser URL is `http://[my_host]/mysite/app/home.html#/path_a` so `$location` always returns `http://[my_host]/mysite/app/home.html`.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

### UPDATE

I figured it out. The issue was caused by something different. I did not had the $location provider in the template scope so the following link LINK was always pointing to the current browser url (hash excluded).

Comment: In my testing, when the browser URL is `http://[my_host]/mysite/app/home.html#/path_a/path_b`, I see the following:

$location.absUrl(): `http://[my_host]/mysite/app/home.html#/path_a/path_b`
$location.path(): `/path_a/path_b`
$location.hash(): `''`
$location.url(): `/path_a/path_b`

From your question, I gather this is NOT the case when you try those?

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks any way for your time.

Comment: Thought it might be something like that. Glad you found it!